# regex in r to replace a string with no special characters

Tags: regex, r

i'm practicing my regex with r on a football schedule and can't figure this out

I'm essentially trying to change any home game to the string HOME.  here is a snippet of the schedule_team dataframe that I am using:

```
  Team   w1   w2   w3   w4   w5   w6   w7   w8   w9  w10  w11  w12  w13  w14
1  ARI   SD @NYG   SF  BYE @DEN  WSH @OAK  PHI @DAL  STL  DET @SEA @ATL   KC
2  ATL   NO @CIN   TB @MIN @NYG  CHI @BAL  DET  BYE  @TB @CAR  CLE  ARI  @GB
3  BAL  CIN  PIT @CLE  CAR @IND  @TB  ATL @CIN @PIT  TEN  BYE  @NO   SD @MIA
```

non home teams have a @ symbol to begin the string.  home teams do not.  using regex in python I believe all home teams can be selected with regex like: ^([A-Z])\w+  .. essentially saying begins with a capital.  this doesn't work in R because of the \w among other errors.

Here is what I tried (and failed):

```
str_replace_all(as.matrix(schedule_teams), "[[^([A-Z])\w+]]", "HOME")
```

is there an easier way to change all home teams to HOME?

thanks in advance

Comment: Off the topic, but you'd be better off re-formatting this into a long-form data frame, each row being a team and having the columns "where" and "opponent".  It would be easier to read and would only have 30 or so rows.

Comment: @RichardScriven  thanks Richard.. that is my plan, hopefully getting familiar with the tidyr package to do so!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regular expression syntax is incorrect, you have it wrapped inside of cascading [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and you are trying to use a capturing group inside of the class which causes the pattern to fail when it reaches the closing `)`

To be concise, your regular expression currently defines a set of characters (**not what you want**) then fails.

```
[[^([A-Z]  # any character of: '[', '^', '(', '[', 'A' to 'Z'
```

To fix this issue you need to remove the character classes and the capturing group that you have placed inside, making sure you double escape `\w` in your regular expression pattern and then it should work for you.

I tested this on my console and it worked fine.

```
> df[,-1] <- str_replace_all(as.matrix(df[,-1]), '^[A-Z]\\w+', 'HOME')
##   Team   w1   w2   w3   w4   w5   w6   w7   w8   w9  w10  w11  w12  w13  w14
## 1  ARI HOME @NYG HOME HOME @DEN HOME @OAK HOME @DAL HOME HOME @SEA @ATL HOME
## 2  ATL HOME @CIN HOME @MIN @NYG HOME @BAL HOME HOME  @TB @CAR HOME HOME  @GB
## 3  BAL HOME HOME @CLE HOME @IND  @TB HOME @CIN @PIT HOME HOME  @NO HOME @MIA
```

Aside from using the `stringr` library, you can do this using `sub` if you insist using a regular expression.

```
> df[,-1] <- sub('^[A-Z]\\w+', 'HOME', as.matrix(df[,-1]))
```

And here is an approach without using regular expression:

```
> m <- as.matrix(df[-1])
> m[substr(m,0,1) != '@'] <- 'HOME'
> cbind(df[1], m)
##   Team   w1   w2   w3   w4   w5   w6   w7   w8   w9  w10  w11  w12  w13  w14
## 1  ARI HOME @NYG HOME HOME @DEN HOME @OAK HOME @DAL HOME HOME @SEA @ATL HOME
## 2  ATL HOME @CIN HOME @MIN @NYG HOME @BAL HOME HOME  @TB @CAR HOME HOME  @GB
## 3  BAL HOME HOME @CLE HOME @IND  @TB HOME @CIN @PIT HOME HOME  @NO HOME @MIA
```